# German translation of "wash my hands of something"

Tags: translation, english-to-german, phrase

There is an english expression that goes *"wash my hands of something"*. A definition of that can be found [in the Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/wash-your-hands-of-someone-or-something) and if I am not mistaken comes from the [Pontius Pilate story](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontius_Pilate).

What it basically means is (loosely translated) that *I refuse to take part in something / make a decision on some issue / stay neutral*.

Is there a German analogy to that?

Does the phrase

> Da mische ich mich (lieber) nicht ein.

convey the same meaning?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the German Bible translation, King David said in *Psalm 26,6*:

> Ich wasche meine Hände zum Zeichen meiner Unschuld, so darf ich mich deinem Altar nähern und ihn feierlich umschreiten.

Pontius Pilatus seemed to know that tradition. Well, at least Matthew wrote it that way in *Matthäus 27,24*:

> Als Pilatus sah, dass er so nichts erreichte und dass der Tumult nur immer grösser wurde, ließ er eine Schüssel mit Wasser bringen. Für alle sichtbar wusch er sich die Hände und sagte: „Ich bin am Blut dieses Menschen nicht schuldig. Die Verantwortung dafür tragt ihr!“

This does not mean Pontius Pilatus is unmoved. Rather, he strongly opposes what happens but sees his hands bound due to the circumstances.

The typical German saying is **sich die Hände in Unschuld waschen.**

> Egal was ihr da treibt, ich wasche meine Hände in Unschuld.

Your phrase

> Da mische ich mich (lieber) nicht ein.

doesn't fit exactly as it doesn't express the opposition. You can't fix that with the particle *lieber* because that one expresses doubt. But there is no doubt about the opposition.

Comment: You could add that the German proverb goes back to the (slightly incorrect) Luther translation of the Psalm.

Comment: Luther 1545: JCh wassche meine Hende mit vnschuld / Vnd halte mich HERR zu deinem Altar.

Answer (score 4):

"Da mische ich mich (lieber) nicht ein" is OK. It is often used when one doesn't want to take part in a conflict.

Another common, although somewhat colloquial phrase which is a bit more general in my view is:

> Ich halte mich da raus.

Answer (score 2):

Nicht ganz analog zu "Ich wasche meine Hände in Unschuld", aber jedenfalls eng verwandt und nach wie vor sehr beliebt ist

> Meine Name ist Hase

als Verkürzung von

> Mein Name ist Hase, ich weiß von nichts!

Eine Erklärung zur Herkunft des Spruchs findet sich auf der Webiste [Wissenschaft im Dialog](https://www.wissenschaft-im-dialog.de/projekte/wieso/artikel/beitrag/woher-stammt-die-redewendung-mein-name-ist-hase/), wo unter anderem zu  lesen ist:

> "Über die Entstehung dieser sprichwörtlichen Redensart wird in der Fachliteratur eine Anekdote angegeben, in welcher im Jahre 1855 der Heidelberger Jura-Student Viktor Hase einem Kommilitonen seinen Studentenausweis überlassen hatte, nachdem dieser in einem Duell seinen Gegner erschossen hatte. Mit dem fremden Ausweis gelangte der Flüchtling  wohlbehalten über die Grenze nach Frankreich, wo er den Ausweis verlor. Der Ausweis wurde gefunden und ans Heidelberger Universtitätsgericht geschickt. Bei der Befragung soll sich der Jurist Viktor Hase so geäußert haben: „Mein Name ist Hase, ich verneine die Generalfragen, ich weiß von nichts!“ Die schlagfertige Antwort verbreitete sich daraufhin leicht gekürzt und ist nun in aller Munde (vgl.: Krüger-Lorenzen, Kurt:  Deutsche Redensarten und was dahinter steckt; Heyne München 2001)."

Ob man diese Herleitung nun glauben will oder nicht, ist jedem selbst überlassen. Ich wasche meine Hände in Unwissen.

Answer (score 0):

Another expression in Germany is "Ich bin die Schweiz", because neutrality is one of the most important principles of Switzerland's foreign policy.

Comment: interesting answer. Should I expect to be understood with this one?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis    Not necessarily by everybody. You may expect people with increased speed of cognitive processing to make the correct link...

Comment: @Ev.Kounis, I grew up in Baden Württemberg and there, the expression is common. I am not sure about the rest of Germany.